# Improve Boost Property Tree performance

Tags: c++, optimization, boost, boost-propertytree

I coded a simple JSON wrapper on top of boost property trees (available at [github](https://github.com/mariolpantunes/JSONObject)).

The focus of the library is to mimic interface of org.json (java JSON library). However it is taking 2 seconds to insert a string array of 1000000 (1M) elements.

For comparison the same code in java, using org.json, takes only 0.071 seconds.
One interesting thing that I saw was that the java code used all my cores while my c++ code only uses one core.

Is there a way to optimize this?
Does boost have a multi-thread property tree?

Comment: The process of booting an OS and the process of adding elements to a JSON structure is quite different. If you do not have any useful contributions just spare me of your rudeness.

Comment: How long does the same thing take in JSON? Have you used a profiler to determine where it is being slow?

Comment: The same code in java, using org.json, takes 0.071 seconds.

Comment: I have same experience. Use boost property tree to deal with json is significantly slow. It's even slower than python script for doing same thing. I eventually switched to jansson which is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since i was unable to find any method to improve Boost property tree performance I started developing a Cpp native library.
It was the same interface, but faster, and more compliant with the JSON format.
The code is publicly available [here](https://github.com/ATNoG/JSONObject).